# Catch->Then->Catch example with Bluebird

Tags: node.js, typescript, bluebird

I am trying to setup my code flow using promises, but I am failing to grasp what is possible to do, and what is not.

Let's say I have a register function, where I want to:

a) register a user
b) log the registering process
c) send an activation email 
d) return the answer to the callback

I start by seeing if a user already exists, and if it doesn't, then a `StorageError` is thrown, and caught in the next `catch` block.

```
let basicRegister = function (request: any, reply: any) {
    let seneca = this;
    let act = Promise.promisify(seneca.act, { context: seneca });

    User.getByEmail(email).then(function (user: any) {
        throw new OperationError("Email already exists");
    }).catch(StorageError, function (err: any) {    
        return User.create().catch(function (err: any) {
            throw new OperationError(err.message);
        });
    }).then((user: any) => {    
        return UserActivity.create().catch(function (err: any) {
            throw new OperationError(err.message);
        });
    }).then(function (confirmationMessage: any) {

        //how can I obtain the user object here?

        return { ok: true, user: user };
    }).catch(OperationError, (error: any) => {
        console.log(error);
        return { ok: false, message: error.message };
    }).asCallback(reply);
}
```

Based on the code above, I have the following questions:

1 - Is it normal to have catch and then interleaved as in this example? If not, what is the correct approach?

2 - Is it possible to obtain the `user` object from a previous `then` in the final `then`?

Let me know if you need any more information

Comment: Not sure about 1), but as for 2), you can declare `var finalUser;` (or whatever sounds logical) in the line before `User.getByEmail` and then `finalUser = user` in your second `.then()` block, so the `finalUser` variable is available in your final `then()` block

Comment: Your suggestion worked nicely, thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For accessing the userobject, you could just continue in the scope where the user object exists.Regarding your error handling: You only need to catch errors at the very end. They get passed through the promise chain anyway.

```
let basicRegister = function(request: any, reply: any) {
    let seneca = this;
    let act = Promise.promisify(seneca.act, {
        context: seneca
    });

    User.getByEmail(email).then(function(user: any) {
        throw new OperationError("Email already exists");
    }).catch(StorageError, function(err: any) {
        return User.create();
    }).then((user) => {
        return UserActivity.create()
            .then((confirmationMessage) => {
                return {
                    ok: true,
                    user: user
                };
            });
    }).catch(OperationError, (error: any) => {
        console.log(error);
        return {
            ok: false,
            message: error.message
        };
    }).asCallback(reply);
}
```

Comment: I was trying to avoid a "promise hell", and as so perhaps Fissio's comment could work better. About your answer, do you mean that I can move the first catch statement to the end of the chain? Am I still able to "forward" results to the `then` statement?

Comment: @ManuelReis no you need the first catch as you transform it into a non throwing eg no-error block. But you can get rid of every other catch.

Comment: Yes, you're right, in this particular example I could remove the `catch` statements, but I am actually using those catches to customize the error message. So, just to be clear, is it correct to have `catch` -> `then` -> `catch` statements interleaved?

Comment: Yes you can do that.